# I can't import tree from sklearn in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I tried to import sklearn by

```
from sklearn import tree
```

but it gives error:

```
No name 'tree' in module 'sklearn'
```

I tried using anaconda but it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem but I am not sure if this will be the solution for everyone.

I uninstalled sklearn (`pip uninstall scikit-learn`) and also uninstalled anaconda from my pc. I believe that I had installed anaconda incorrectly before. After installing anaconda again, I did `conda install scikit-learn` and it installed perfectly.